# Kafka: Find Controller ID in a cluster using Kraft protocol

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

How to find the current controller ID, preferably using command-line, on a Kafka cluster which is using Kraft.

Kafka Version: 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using KRaft, a cluster no longer has a single controller. Instead, nodes in the cluster that are running with the "controller" role, all take part in the *controller metadata quorum*.

The reason that tools are reporting seemingly random IDs is [because of an intentional choice to return a random controller participant ID](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/b2dea17041157ceee741041d23783ff993b88ef1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/metadata/KRaftMetadataCache.scala#L290-L305) in the existing metadata APIs. This helps in distributing load equally on the nodes participating in the quorum.

Underneath, the participants of the metadata quorum are maintaining a special topic that is replicated with the Raft consensus algorithm. This topic has a leader and you can get the *leader ID* of that topic. But it is important to note that this is not equal to the controller on a ZK-backed cluster, that role no longer exists when running with KRaft, and as mentioned is now instead a role shared by many nodes.

You should be able to fetch the current leader ID of a cluster by [requesting metadata](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#The_Messages_Metadata) for the `__cluster_metadata` topic, or as suggested in another answer by using the kafka-metadata-quorum script.

Comment: Actually, controller_id is not even necessarily a quorum participant, but any broker in the cluster I think. I'll update this answer once I find the time.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you mean Active Controller ID.

Kafka 3.3 comes with the kafka-metadata-quorum tool.

```
> bin/kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server  broker_host:port describe --status
ClusterId:              fMCL8kv1SWm87L_Md-I2hg
LeaderId:               3002
...
```

Docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kraft_metadata_tool

Comment: I tried about four thrid-party Kafka UIs and they all are reporting a different Active Controller ID on every refresh - even one second apart. Whereas the above command is reporting the same  Leader ID consistently, which is what I would expect. But why would the UIs report it differently? Is there a way I can check when the leader/active controller was elected?